# twitter bootstrap good practice for applying classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a project using twitter bootstrap.

I wanted to know if it is a bad practice to use our custom class names along with bootstrap classes in the same div or container.

For Eg :-

```
<div class="container user-profile"> // is this bad practice?

</div> 

Should we create another div for class user-profile :-

<div class="container">
    <div class="user-profile">

    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see why this would be bad practice, I am sure that you can safely add your own classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you are referring to bad practice is *not* bad practice, especially in light of cluttering the DOM with additional elements.

**It is *better* to add additional classes to an element than to add additional DOM elements each with a new class**

There is nothing wrong with adding additional classes to elements, this is how CSS has been created to work. However, you need to be aware that frameworks like Bootstrap rely on their classes for the functionality they offer, so by adding your own you do risk style collision (e.g overwriting a style Bootstrap otherwise was relying on).

With that in mind, Bootstrap uses fairly effective selectors making it unlikely you can so readily override its functionality, but keep it in mind if you're experiencing unexpected side-effects.

DOM elements are there for creating ***purpose*** (holding content), CSS is there for creating ***style***, as such, if you are looking to simply add style, dont also add purpose!